# How to move JUNG nodes(vertices) by changing their location in the code and not by mouse?

Tags: jung, jung2

I am implementing an interface for creating graph nodes and connecting them using **JUNG**.

I want to create some nodes that can move from one existing node to another node using the `edge` between two nodes as their **path** (It will be used for showing some `Data Packets` being transferred between nodes that are like `Hosts`).

There is some information on the internet about how to make the **JUNG** nodes(vertices) movable by mouse but there is no info about moving them by `modifying values in the code`.

Even if there is someway for moving the nodes is it possible and efficient to move the node between nodes using the edge between them as the moving path in **JUNG** library?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can forcibly move a vertex with the `setLocation` method of the layout. I have built something that is quite similar to your request. It produces a vertex that moves from vertex A to vertex B in a direct line. If your edges are straight then it might work:

```
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.layout.AbstractLayout;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.util.IterativeProcess;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.VisualizationViewer;

public class VertexCollider extends IterativeProcess {

    private static final String COLLIDER = "Collider";
    private AbstractLayout<String, Number> layout;
    private VisualizationViewer<String, Number> vv;
    private Point2D startLocation;
    private Point2D endLocation;
    private Double moveX;
    private Double moveY;

    public VertexCollider(AbstractLayout<String, Number> layout, VisualizationViewer<String, Number> vv, String vertexA, String vertexB) {
        this.layout = layout;
        this.vv = vv;
        startLocation = layout.transform(vertexA);
        endLocation = layout.transform(vertexB);
    }

    public void initialize() {
        setPrecision(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        layout.getGraph().addVertex(COLLIDER);
        layout.setLocation(COLLIDER, startLocation);
        moveX = (endLocation.getX() - startLocation.getX()) / getMaximumIterations();
        moveY = (endLocation.getY() - startLocation.getY()) / getMaximumIterations();
    }

    @Override
    public void step() {
        layout.setLocation(COLLIDER, layout.getX(COLLIDER) + moveX, layout.getY(COLLIDER) + moveY);
        vv.repaint();
        setPrecision(Math.max(Math.abs(endLocation.getX() - layout.transform(COLLIDER).getX()),
            Math.abs(endLocation.getY() - layout.transform(COLLIDER).getY())));
        if (hasConverged()){
            layout.getGraph().removeVertex(COLLIDER);
        }
    }
}
```

You could instantiate this for example with this code:

```
    VertexCollider vtxCol = new VertexCollider(layout, vv, "nameOfVertexA", "nameOfVertexB");
    vtxCol.setMaximumIterations(100);
    vtxCol.setDesiredPrecision(1);
    vtxCol.initialize();
    Animator animator = new Animator(vtxCol);
    animator.start();
```

Painting straight edges:

[Code Example](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CEUQFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.columbia.edu%2F~sh553%2Fteaching%2Fw3134-s07%2Fhomework%2FjungExample.java&ei=aVGmVOXaG8j4Us2-hKgL&usg=AFQjCNHkKuOvB5nTc6ybPNXWIs_WAtKxww&bvm=bv.82001339,d.d24&cad=rja)

Comment: Is there any attribute that by setting it the edges become straight?, because by default the edges are not straight.